# Preventing EF6 from validating related entities

Tags: entity-framework-6

I have code similar to this in my Cities controller:

```
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);

        var city = DbContext.Cities.SingleOrDefault(o => o.CityId == cityId);
        DbContext.Entry(city).State = EntityState.Modified;
        city.name = "test";

        DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

City has a foriegn Key to State. When it hits SaveChanges, it's erroring because the properties on the virtual State entity are all null. How do I get it to not validate the State entity? I have specifically NOT included the state entity in the SingleOrDefault as it's not relevant. I suppose I could load it but then I'd have to load all related entities, when I just want to edit the city name. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an Editor inheritance bug.

I had this in my cities model:

```
public virtual State State { get; set; } = new State();
```

Removing the `= new State()` did the trick.